# Writing to S3 with spark raises java.io.IOException: file doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm trying to write a dataframe to S3.

Strangely it complains that the file doesn't exist when I'm trying to write it.

My code:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('column1', IntegerType())])
data = [(x,) for x in range(10)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

url = "s3://XXX/YYY/write_test.csv"
df.write.csv(url)
```

The exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.csv.
: java.io.IOException: /YYY/write_test.csv doesn't exist
```

Using

- spark 2.1.1
- aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
- hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar

Comment: Perhaps I answered my own question: changing "s3://" to "s3a://" it now works.

Comment: While changing from "s3://" to "s3a" gave me "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/pool/ConnPoolControl" error. Added the maven dependency, the error vanished